# Html.TagHandler not detecting certain HTML tags

Tags: android, tag-handler

I am writing my own tag handler (below). For some reason, it does not detect certain tags, like `<blockquote>`, or `<a>` as unsupported.

When I debug at the line `if(!SUPPORTED_HTML_TAGS.contains(tag.toLowerCase()))`, passing in HTML containing `<blockquote>` and `<a>`'s in it, I don't even see the  or  tags being detected there. I only see tag appear as "html", and "body". I do see it detect `<table>`, `<tr>`, `<td>` though.

Is this a known issue/bug?

```
private static class RichTextEditorTagHandler implements Html.TagHandler
{
    private final List<String> SUPPORTED_HTML_TAGS =
        Arrays.asList("html", "body", "b", "i", "u", "br", "p", "div", "span");
    private static boolean hasUnsupportedHtml;

    @Override
    public void handleTag(boolean opening, String tag, Editable output, XMLReader xmlReader)
    {
        if (!SUPPORTED_HTML_TAGS.contains(tag.toLowerCase()))
            hasUnsupportedHtml = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23551751/android-taghandler-no-effect-on-standard-tags?rq=1

Comment: answered in https://stackoverflow.com/a/44525485/6248510